# Slick query very slow

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm trying to learn Slick and have got a Postgres database up and running. I made a tiny program to test it like this:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

object Names extends Table[(String)]("names")     
{
    def name = column[String]("name", O.PrimaryKey)
    def * = name
}

object DbTest
{
    val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/names", 
                              driver = "org.postgresql.Driver")

    def main(args : Array[String]) =
    {
        print("Doing something... ")

        db withTransaction 
        {
            Query(Names) foreach 
            { 
                case (name) =>
                    println(name)
            }
        }
        println("... done!")
    }
}
```

The problem is that it takes about 5 seconds for anything to happen after `print("Doing something... ")`. If I duplicate the `db withTransaction` block, both blocks are executed in quick succession after those first 5 seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: When you connect to postgres from command line, how long does it take? Because I don't see anything that should take that long.

Comment: It's virtually instant!

Comment: How many rows are returned from the query?

Comment: Just one - "John Doe".

Comment: OK two more questions, what versions of slick, scala and possibly postgresql driver are you using? And if you are on linux could you try to connect with url jdbc:postgresql:names instead of jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/names? I'm not sure if that works on Windows too. Now that I am home I could try it, and your code takes just a fraction of a second for me with scala 2.10.2 and slick 1.0.1.

Comment: Slick version 1.0.1, Scala verson 2.10.2, Postgresql is 9.1-901.jdbc4 as used in my build.sbt file. Setting to the shorter connect string makes no noticable difference.

Comment: OK, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I know the specific problem, but there are a few things in your code example that would be a concern for performance.

1) Make sure you are using [Query Templates](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#query-templates). There is quite a bit of overhead building the query with Slick that you don't want to repeat on each query.

2) You also shouldn't use threadLocalSession in real code (see thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/Sg42HDEK34Q)). It should look something like below.

3) Use a connection pool like [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).

Example:

```
val pool = // some connection pool like C3P0 or other

Database.forDataSource(pool).withSession { implicit session: Session =>
  ...
}
```